# What's the intuition behind SUM(1/COUNTIF(range,range))?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Michael Price. [*Office 2019 in easy steps*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1840788208). p. 83.

[image]

[Exceljet (though it discusses SUMPRODUCT)](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif)

> ## Explanation
>
> To count the number of unique or distinct values in a range of cells (named "data" in the example below), you can use a formula based on the [COUNTIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) and [SUMPRODUCT](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) functions.

and [Spreadsheets Made Easy](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/how-to-count-unique-values/) don't expatiate why:

1. `range` is repeated? Isn't this superfluous?
2. take the reciprocal?
3. sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the gist:

> 1. range is repeated? Isn't this superfluous?

COUNTIF needs both a range and the "if" criteria.  The range is repeated because the first provides the range and the second provides the criteria.  This compares each cell in the range to the same collection of values, and counts the matches.  Note that using this structure requires that it be handled as an array, because you are using an array of IF criteria rather than a single target.

Here's an example.  Suppose your data looks like this, and you want to find the number of unique values:

[image]

When you use the same data as the list of criteria, the two arrays look like this (ignore the cell locations, this is just for illustration):

[image]

COUNTIF works its way through the data list, starting with `horse` in A2.  It compares `horse` to all of the values in the criteria list (B2:B7 in this illustration), and counts 3 matches.

Then it compares `dog` to the criteria list and finds 1 match.  Then `cat`, and finds 2 matches.  Then `horse` in A5 and finds 3 matches.  And so forth through the list.  The resulting counts look like this:

[image]

So `horse` occurs 3 times.  Each time it finds all three matches in the criteria list.  Similarly, `cat` occurs twice, and each time it finds both matches in the criteria list.

> 2. take the reciprocal?

Every time a cell has a match, it gets counted.  So any value that gets repeated gets counted multiple times.  The reciprocal turns each count result into a fraction.  If a value appears only once, it will get a count of 1, and the reciprocal will be 1.  If a value appears "N" times, the result array will contain N repeats of a count of N matches.  The reciprocal turns that into N repeats of 1/N.  The reciprocals look like this:

[image]

When those get added, the reciprocals sum to 1 for each value, which is what you want for a count of that unique value.  Adding the reciprocals produces a total of `3`, which is the number of unique values in the data.

> 3. sum?

If you use an array formula (confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>), that creates a results array, which you can sum with SUM.  The sum adds up the single counts and the multiple fractional counts to produce a net count of unique values.

Instead of SUM and an array formula, you can use SUMPRODUCT with a normal formula.  SUMPRODUCT handles array data without needing an array formula.

Here are a couple of additional explanations with examples that show the internal array values.  https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html demonstrates using SUM with an array formula.  https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif demonstrates using SUMPRODUCT with a normal formula.